# Portable NetBeans with c++ support

Tags: java, c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin

I use NetBeans on Windows 7 to code c++ and I use Cygwin compilers.

Having S:\cygwin\bin in PATH evironment variable has several drawbacks. i.e. The setup is not portable and most importantly other 4200 unnececcary executables are in PATH. Which can cause problems when other software has or expects other executable with conflicting name.

That is why I would like to modify PATH variable only for NetBeans and use other PATH settings system wide.

Here is the command by which I try to start and use NetBeans:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;S:\cygwin\bin &&"S:\software\programming\NetBeans_JavaSE_8.0_Portable\NetBeansPortable.exe"
```

Everything looks fine. NetBeans can find the compiler tools, creates new project. It even compiles the sources correctly. It produce correct compiled exe file of my program. I can start it from command line (after modifing PATH variable again, for that cmd session).

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;S:\cygwin\bin&&"D:\smazat\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\cppapplication_1.exe"
```

However my program cannot be stareted within netbeans by clicking green "Run Project" button.

It says: `java.lang.NullPointer Exception`

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the log of compiling:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/smazat/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/smazat/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/smazat/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/smazat/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

Here is what "Run" tab says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

RUN FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 229ms)
```

Comment: please share the entire log trace.

Comment: The log does not say much. But I added it now. Thanks.